# No debug information in Keil when I try to simulate a STM32F103C6 in proteus ISIS

Tags: simulation, debugging, proteus, keil

how are you?. I need to simulate a project I what I'm working made with keil in proteus, Labcenter's people enfasizes in that those simulations needs both the .elf file and the dwarf2 file, in Keil with the option --dwarf2 the compiler can generate the dwarf file and giving the extension in the C/C++ and output tab respectively but when I run the simulation in proteus then the proteus log shows the following messages:

```
[ELF] Loading ARM ELF file '..\..\..\..\Desktop\Proyecto\Objects\Luz.elf'. [U61_CM3CORE]

[ELF] No ".debug_line" section, cannot associate addresses to source lines [U61_CM3CORE]

[ELF] No ".debug_info" or ".debug_abbrev" or ".debug_str" section, cannot extract variable location & 
`type data [U61_CM3CORE]
```

So the problem is keil, Can anyone tell me how to generate both files in keil?.

Thanks in advance for the help.